# Difference between Repa and DPH

Tags: haskell, repa, data-parallel-haskell

I recently read the [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/ndp/haskell-beats-C.pdf) on upcoming generalized stream fusion in `vector` and `DPH` libraries. It seems to be very interesting development. I am now starting to experiment with `DPH` (starting with GHC 7.6, and plan to upgrade to 7.8 SIMD version when it comes out). I also see from `Repa` library documentation that it can do the parallel array work. `Repa` seems to be the mature version compared to `DPH` which wasn't deemed ready as of GHC 7.4. Now that `DPH` seems to be maturing, I am wondering what are the main pros and cons between `Repa` and `DPH` packages, as of GHC 7.6. I searched StackOverflow and google, but couldn't find comparisons between `Repa` and `DPH`. Hence, this question.

Comment: @leventov: That's a correct answer. You should probably move it to an actual answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the page about DPH](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell#Project_status) on HaskellWiki:

> DPH focuses on irregular data parallelism. For regular data parallel code in Haskell, please consider using the companion library Repa, which builds on the parallel array infrastructure of DPH.

Comment: so no other major differences between Repa and DPH other than that? For example, what about generalized stream fusion and simd instructions - will they be available in Repa as well? The paper focussed on Vector and DPH, with no mention of Repa (except briefly in introduction). That is why I thought Repa might be on the way to be replaced by DPH, and started thinking about differences that would prevent that.

Comment: @sal according to Ben Lippmeier, stream fusion is on the way in Repa 4 ([link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/haskell-repa/Wm5ZIKhOI5g/UcdYgN1PtdsJ)). SIMD instructions support is not a library but compiler concern. As far as I understand situation, in some time it will be sufficient to obey some conditions and provide GHC compilation flags to obtain vectorized machine code from the plain Haskell. Libraries like `vector`, `repa`, `dph` will just follow these rules.